# Spark column rlike converts int to boolean

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I'm using regex with Spark's column rlike to extract the last digit from a string. The problem is that after it extracts the digit, it automatically gets converted to Boolean. Is there a way for me to stop it from being automatically converted to Boolean?

```
test.withColumn("Quarter", $"Month".rlike("\\d+$"))
```

For example:

Input:

```
2015 Q 1
2015 Q 1
2015 Q 2
2015 Q 2
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
true
```

Expected: `1 1 2 2`

I tried casting it after to integer but all it does is that returns 1 because it gets converted from Boolean to Int.

```
test.withColumn("Quarter", $"Month".rlike("\\d+$").cast("integer"))
```

Comment: Try `.withColumn("Quarter",regexp_replace('Month,".* (\\d+)$","$1"))`, well, I might mix up the columns.

Comment: does one of the answer solve your problem? then please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark has a function to extract by matching the regex, You can use [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function for this.

```
scala> val df = Seq("2015 Q 1", "2015 Q 1", "2015 Q 2", "2015 Q 2").toDF("col1") 
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.withColumn("Quarter",regexp_extract($"col1", ".*(\\d+)$", 1)).show

+--------+-------+
|    col1|Quarter|
+--------+-------+
|2015 Q 1|      1|
|2015 Q 1|      1|
|2015 Q 2|      2|
|2015 Q 2|      2|
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the expected behavior, `rlike` is for filtering. Try `regex_extract` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

```
df.withColumn("Q", regexp_extract($"month", ".*(\\d)$", 1))
```

or even substring from the same package may be enough in your case:

```
df.withColumn("Q", substring($"month",7,7))
```

These columns can the be casted to an integer of you wish (although is rather parsing than casting...)